# GLSL 110 does not allow sub- or super-matrix constructors

Tags: c#, macos, opengl, glsl, opentk

I am trying to convert a 330 shader to 110 but can't find a work around for:

```
v_norm = normalize(mat3(modelview) * vNormal);
```

The error returned is:

```
GLSL 110 does not allow sub- or super-matrix constructors
```

The complete shader:

```
#version 110

attribute  vec3 vPosition;
attribute  vec3 vNormal;
varying vec3 v_norm;

uniform mat4 modelview;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = modelview * vec4(vPosition, 1.0);
    v_norm = normalize(mat3(modelview) * vNormal);
    v_norm = vNormal;
}
```

Comment: If you assign again v_norm to vNormal at the end if your shader, the assignment above where you have your problem is useless and can be safely removed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll assume that you don't understand what "sub- or super-matrix construction" is, since if you did, the workaround would be obvious.

The statement `mat3(modelview)` tells [GLSL to construct a `mat3`](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Data_Type_%28GLSL%29#Matrix_constructors). But the matrix passed to it is a `mat4`, a 4x4 matrix. Obviously there are 16 numbers instead of the 9 used by `mat3`.

Under the rules of decent GLSL versions, this would extract the upper-left 3x3 sub-matrix of the given `mat4`. GLSL 1.10 is not decent.

So the workaround for this is to do it manually. Construct a `mat3` made from 9 values, taken from the upper-left portion of the `modelview` matrix. Or from three vectors:

```
mat3(modelview[0].xyz, modelview[1].xyz, modelview[2].xyz)
```

Comment: No I didn't, but I do now, thanks, you explained it clearly. So is there are cleaner way than this: `mat3 NicolBolas = mat3(modelview[0][0], modelview[0][1], modelview[0][2], modelview[1][0], modelview[1][1], modelview[1][2], modelview[2][0], modelview[2][1], modelview[2][2]);` ?

Comment: @livin_amuk: See edits. I assume that your old version of GLSL can construct matrices from (column) vectors.